# How to enable the status bar in String.xml in Android Studio that I suddently clicked on Hide Notification

Tags: java, android, string

[image]

I've been stuck with this issue, please help me. I right clicked on string.xml file but it did not open the file editor.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, rename your `string.xml` file to `strings.xml`

then delete this line in your string.xml file, save it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> //delete this line
```

now click menu **File---Close Project** and reopen your project and open `strings.xml` file again.